# Component Identification - Latching Relay?

Tags: identification, latching-relay

I have, from my limited knowledge, what may be a latching relay.  It was made by FR Ltd of Wimborne, Dorset.  I presume this is Flight Refuelling Ltd.  It is called a Memstore RSC-68.

Anyone know anything more about this, or where I might find some further info?

It doesn't come up on a Google search.  Presumably a pretty rare item.

[image: side view]

[image: top view]

Comment: Yes it's rare and it's value depends on who needs it and how soon. A better description might be "extinct" , as latching relays tend to be double throw like SPDT for the most common application. https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/relays/signal-relays-up-to-2-amps/189?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv1409=27&sf=0&FV=a8c0004%2C1f140000%2Cffe000bd%2C1140050&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: Check ebay for value, if there isn't a comparable part, there is no market for it to find the price

Comment: Thanks for comments.  Checked EBay, nothing on there, but it does have "FR" imprinted in the plastic on the ends of the package, with the letters vertically offset, which appears to have been used in marketing by Flight Refuelling.  It's no use to me - will put it on EBay and see what I can get!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [cynergy3](https://www.cynergy3.com/sites/default/files/FRS22000%202016.pdf) bistable relays.

May or may not be relay-ted. but the location, product and even part number seem suspiciously close.

I don't see the exact name F.R. Limited or F.R. LTD. in UK company registrations.

Comment: upvote for relay-ted ... lol

Comment: Thanks - seems too much of a coincidence that they're not related.  Could be that Cynergy3 was a spin-off of Flight Refuelling at one time, possibly.  I don't know how old it is - probably 1970's - it was part of my Dad's collection of electronic bits 'n' pieces from his time at Plessey, Templecombe.

Comment: I should have added a photo of the end of the relay - it has "FR" imprinted in the plastic, vertically offset, which is the same symbol as used historically by Flight Refuelling, hence the perceved connection.